# Devise gem NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, registration

I'm trying to implement Devise into my project, but after doing all the installation steps for devise when I try to visit the endpoint users/sign_up I get the error:

NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new

```
    <%= link_to "View All", tags_path, class: "item" %>
    <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
      <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag), class: "item" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to "Create New", new_tag_path, class: "item" %>
```

I tried adding a method to my application controller to bring my tag model access global, but that hasn't solved the nilClass issue still. I'm using rails 5.2, devise 4.2

This bit of code that is making rails act up lives on my navbar, which I have living in the application.html.erb file.  I made a global tags method in my application controller to solve this, but to no avail.

```
  def find_all_tags
        @tags = Tag.all
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you set it as a `before_action` in `application_controller`? i.e. `before_action :find_all_tags`

Comment: haha, that was the issue.  Can't believe I didn't see that.  Thanks!